# BPF verifier rejetcs the use of an inode ptr as a key

Tags: bpf, ebpf

I'm attempting to implement an eBPF code where I have a BPF MAP with the key of type  `struct inode *` and some value.
Please see the below sample code

```
      struct value {
        char data[10];
    };
    struct bpf_map_def info SEC("maps") ={
        .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
        .max_entries =  100,
        .key_size = sizeof(struct inode *),
        .value_size = sizeof(struct value),
        .map_flags = BPF_F_NO_PREALLOC,
    };

    SEC("fexit/vfs_unlink")
    int BPF_PROG(
    vfs_unlink_exit,
    const struct user_namespace *mnt_userns,
    const struct inode *dir,
    const struct dentry *dentry,
    const struct inode **delegated_inode,
    int ret)
{

    struct inode * p = BPF_CORE_READ(dentry,d_inode);

    struct value *val = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&info, p);
    if (val == NULL)
    {
        bpf_printk("not handling");
        return 0;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The verifier does not like this :

```
   libbpf: -- BEGIN DUMP LOG ---
libbpf: 
R1 type=ctx expected=fp
; int BPF_PROG(
0: (b7) r2 = 48
; int BPF_PROG(
1: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r1 +16)
func 'vfs_unlink' arg2 has btf_id 691 type STRUCT 'dentry'
2: (0f) r3 += r2
last_idx 2 first_idx 0
regs=4 stack=0 before 1: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r1 +16)
regs=4 stack=0 before 0: (b7) r2 = 48
3: (bf) r1 = r10
; 
4: (07) r1 += -16
; struct inode * p = BPF_CORE_READ(dentry,d_inode);
5: (b7) r2 = 8
6: (85) call bpf_probe_read_kernel#113
last_idx 6 first_idx 0
regs=4 stack=0 before 5: (b7) r2 = 8
; struct inode * p = BPF_CORE_READ(dentry,d_inode);
7: (79) r2 = *(u64 *)(r10 -16)
; struct value *val = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&info, p);
8: (18) r1 = 0xffff93c9f43fc000
10: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#1
R2 type=inv expected=fp, pkt, pkt_meta, map_key, map_value
processed 10 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0

libbpf: -- END LOG --
```

Im also not able to pass directly the parameter ptr as the key eg :

```
SEC("fexit/vfs_unlink")
int BPF_PROG(
    vfs_unlink_exit,
    const struct user_namespace *mnt_userns,
    const struct inode *dir,
    const struct dentry *dentry,
    const struct inode **delegated_inode,
    int ret)
{


    struct value *val = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&info, dir);
    if (val == NULL)
    {
        bpf_printk("not handling");
        return 0;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
libbpf: -- BEGIN DUMP LOG ---
libbpf: 
R1 type=ctx expected=fp
; int BPF_PROG(
0: (79) r2 = *(u64 *)(r1 +8)
func 'vfs_unlink' arg1 has btf_id 694 type STRUCT 'inode'
; struct value *val = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&info, dir);
1: (18) r1 = 0xffff93caed64c400
3: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#1
R2 type=ptr_ expected=fp, pkt, pkt_meta, map_key, map_value
processed 3 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0

libbpf: -- END LOG --
```

I don't understand why, as similar approach with eg `struct socket *` works fine.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Kernel v 5.13.0-051300-generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
R2 type=inv expected=fp, pkt, pkt_meta, map_key, map_value
```

The verifier tells you that the second argument (in `R2`) to your call to `bpf_map_lookup_elem()` is not of the expected type. It can point to the stack (`fp`), to packet data (`pkt`) or metadata (`pkt_meta`), or to another map key or value (`map_key`, `map_value`).

In your case, `BPF_CORE_READ()` returns a scalar (`inv`), and `dir` to a BTF id (`ptr_`), and neither is suitable. You could try copying the data for your key to the eBPF stack first (assign it to a temporary variable, and pass a reference to that variable to the helper). You probably don't want to use the *full* `struct inode` as a key anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I actually didn't want to use the full struct inode but rather a pointer to it as a key.
It turns out, as far as I understand, that BPF doesn't allow these operations unless it is a _socket struct *_, which is kind of special case. 
I can though assign it to some _unsigned long_ variable and use it as a key